# Check a string is present in the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a string. Now how to check that the string is present in my array list?

Suppose:

```
str="nokia"
mobiles[0]="samsung"
mobiles[1]="nokia"
mobiles[2]="blackberry"
```

I have tried

```
Boolean match=false;    
for(int j = 0 ; j <= 15 ; j++) {
   match =mobiles[j].compare(str);
   if(match == true) {
     break;
   }
}
```

But .compare(str) is showing error.

Comment: Use `match =mobiles[j].equals(str);`

Comment: That looks like a `String` array, not a `List`.

Comment: Surely you can be more specific than "showing error"? *What* error?

Comment: Do .equals checks the string is present in the string array?

Comment: The error is: The method compare(Phones) in the type Phones is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: That error is impossible. If `mobiles` is a `Phones[]`, then you can't put strings into it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `compare(str)` is throwing an error because there is no function named `compare()` for the String class.

You could use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` for case-insensitive matching. There's also `compareTo()` and `compareToIgnoreCase()` which are closer to what you typed. Note that the compareTo methods return an int value.

You can read up on the method descriptions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Here's an example using `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

```
boolean match = false;    
for (int j = 0; j < mobiles.length; j++)
{
    match = mobiles[j].equalsIgnoreCase(str);
    if (match)
    {
         break;
    }
}
```

I've changed the terminating condition on the loop to use the length of the `mobiles` array. That way you won't need to change a hard-coded value in the event that you change the length of the array. It may also make the intent of the loop a little clearer.

Also as pointed out by ZouZou, writing `match == true` isn't necessary since match is itself a boolean value. This case doesn't seem to require the use of a wrapper class either so you could just declare `match` as the primitive type `boolean`.

Comment: Note : `if(match == true)` could be simplified to `if(match)`

Comment: Also prefer using primitive `boolean` instead of a `Boolean` object.

Answer (score 2):

In the question you mentioned an `ArrayList` but your example shows an Array.
If you really have an `ArrayList`, just use something like:

```
if(mobiles.contains(str))
{
    //code here
}
```

If you have an Array, you can use the same "contains" after converting to `ArrayList`, using something like:

```
if(Arrays.asList(mobiles).contains(str))
{
    //code here
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.toString()` doesn't convert an array to an ArrayList. It does just return a String representation of the content of your array. You're probably looking for `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: Thanks, ZouZou - you are obviously right - and I corrected my answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using an operation for comparing the strings, but to do it directly:

```
boolean match = false;
for (j=0; j<=mobiles.length; j++) {
    if (mobiles[j].equals(str)) {
        match=true; break;
    }
}
```

If you don't need the match boolean later, you can delete that.

Comment: why would you use `==` to compare 2 string?

Comment: Use `equals()`, to compare String values.

Comment: If I were you, I'd either delete this answer or fix it, to avoid further down votes

Comment: @Magnus See the link peeskillet posted in its comment. It explains why.

Comment: Oh that seems quite logic. I fixed it. Thank you all!

Comment: It does work with "==" as long as the strings are declared as constants like in the code snippet of the question asked. But it won't as soon as you use `new String("nokia")`. So it is best to use `equals()` because it will always work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 match =mobiles[j].equalsIgnoreCase(str);
```

`equalsIgnoreCase` compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations. Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same length, and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring case.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)'s [`binarySearch(Object[] a, Object key)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29) method in conjunction with its [`sort(Object[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method.

```
import java.util.Arrays; //put this at the top of your code

//your code here

String[] tempMobiles = mobiles; //temporary array that will be modified
Arrays.sort(tempMobiles); //sorts tempMobiles to prepare it for the next line
if(tempMobiles[Arrays.binarySearch(tempMobiles, str)].equals(str)) //if the string at the location returned by the binarySearch equals str...
{
    match = true; //sets match to true
}
```